# cargar función ngOninit y que rellene un formulario para su edición

Tags: angular, angular6

Estoy tratando de cargar una función cuando se lanza el componente "edit-afiliado" que se llama getAfiliado() y rellenar los campos del formulario con el objeto que devuelve para su posterior edición. Lo estoy llamando en el ngOninit pero mando a imprimir el valor por consola arroja "undefined" y luego si imprime el objeto. Alguna sugerencia para que la función se ejecute al momento de lanzar el componente
Este es el componente para editar.

```
import { Component, OnInit,} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { AfiliadoService } from '../services/afiliado.service';
import { Afiliado } from '../models/afiliado';

@Component({
    selector: 'afiliado-edit',
    templateUrl: '../views/afiliado.edit.html',
    providers: [UserService, AfiliadoService]
})

export class AfiliadoEditComponent implements OnInit{
    public title: string;
    public identida_usuario;
    public token;
    public afiliado: Afiliado;
    public status;
    public today;
    public fecha;

    constructor(
        private _userService: UserService,
        private _afiliadoService: AfiliadoService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router
    ){
        this.title = 'Gestionar afiliado activo',
        this.identida_usuario = this._userService.getIdentida_usuario();
        this.token = this._userService.getToken();
        this.today = new Date();
        this.fecha = formatDate(this.today, 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'en-US', '');     
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log(this.fecha);
        if (this.identida_usuario == null && !this.identida_usuario.sub) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        }else{      

            console.log('cargado...');
            this.getAfiliado();
            console.log(this.getAfiliado());
        }
    }

    getAfiliado(){
        this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];

            this._afiliadoService.getAfiliado(this.token, id).subscribe(
                response => {
                    if(response.status == 'success'){
                    this.afiliado = response.data;                  
                    console.log(this.afiliado);
                    }else{
                        this._router.navigate(['/']);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                }
            );
        });
    }

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.afiliado);
        this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this._afiliadoService.update(this.token, this.afiliado, id).subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.status = response.status;
                    if(response.status != 'success'){
                        this.status = 'error';
                     }else{
                        this.status = response.data;
                        console.log(this.status);
                        this._router.navigate(['/new-beneficiario']);
                     }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(<any>error)
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Aquí esta el servicio para traer el objeto afiliado:

```
getAfiliado(token, id): Observable<any>{
    let params = "authorization="+token;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    return this._http.post(this.url+'/afiliado/detail/'+id, params, {headers: headers});                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

se supone que en la función  getAfiliado() si to va bien this.afiliado = response.data;
por lo que solo se debería imprimir el valor de this.afiliado una vez llamada la función getAfiliado().

```
ngOnInit(){
        console.log(this.fecha);
        if (this.identida_usuario == null && !this.identida_usuario.sub) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        }else{      

          console.log('cargado...');
          this.getAfiliado();
          console.log(this.afiliado);
       }
}
```

ngOnInit se llama inmediatamente después de la creación del componente
por lo que da acceso a las propiedades de tipo Input del componente

Comment: Es correcto, pienso que en teoría el valor de this.afiliado debería rellenar las propiedades tipo input con el two way data binding, pero no es así...

Answer (score 0):

deberías colocar solo lo que corresponde a DI en el constructor, el resto debería estar en el ngOnInit, es probable que vengas al igual que yo del approach de alguna tecnología servidor POO la cual incentiva el uso del constructor para inicializaciones, pero en angular es distinto y los mismos expertos de angular incentivan al uso de ngOnInit para cualquier incializacion en el componente, no el constructor.

ng onInit se llama cuando se termina de construir el dom, la practica normal es colocar lo menos en lógica posible en el constructor.